# Java private modifier confusion

Tags: java, accessor, private-members

I've been writing Java for some years, but I still do not understand why this simple example class below actually passes compilation. In this situation, I would make a getter method for *myInt*, and use that method to fetch the *myInt* from *o* in my *compareTo* method, as *myInt* is declared *private*. Could someone please tell me why on earth this is a legal way to access *o*'s *myInt*?

```
public class B implements Comparable<B> {

    private int myInt = 0;

    public int compareTo(B o) {
        return myInt-o.myInt;
    }

}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `private` has `class` scope. You are still in the same class.

Comment: You are already in the same class with B. Private members are accessible from the same class.

Check: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/variables.html

Access Modifiers
private modifier—the field is accessible only within its own class.

Comment: " a class always has access to its own members" - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html

Comment: Thanks guys, I assumed that was the reason. Post it as an answer and I'll be glad to accept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Oracle's Java Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html)

> Access level modifiers determine whether other classes can use a particular field or invoke a particular method.

Access level has been designed at the class level, and it does not depends on instances.

Answer (score 1):

According to Java API:

> The private modifier specifies that the member can only be accessed in its own class.

As a class always has access to its own members. Your codes are allowed and it will not give your compilation error.

Take a look at this (Changing B to C):

```
class B implements Comparable<B> {

    private int myInt = 0;

    public int compareTo(C o) {
        return myInt-o.myInt;
    }

}

class C
{
    private int myInt = 0;
}
```

If you try changing `B` to `C` (another class). It will give you compilation error.